# classic asp WScript.Shell run error

Tags: shell, vbscript, asp-classic, runtime-error

first time post here.
I am using classic ASP (vbscript) on a windows 2008 server with IIS7.
I am using a command-line utility with the following code:
(the dir is not the actual code but used for testing purposes!)

```
dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "%COMSPEC% /C dir c:\ > c:/tmp/dir.txt", 0, TRUE
set oShell = nothing
```

Now here is the problem: this works on most of my customers servers without any problems,
but one in particular gives an error without a description on the oShell.run line.
If I kill w3wp.exe or in IIS manager, recycle the application pool, it starts working again...
but the error always returns...
I have tried using process monitor, but I don't know what to look for...
Any idea what could be causing this behavior? or possibly some sort of workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try `set oShell = Server.CreateObject("wscript.shell")`

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed response, I didn't receive a notification email?? I tried to add the "server." but it still doesn't work. Was there a reason behind the suggestion, or what it more of a guess?

Comment: For Classic-ASP you needed to add **Server** in front of CreateObject.